# Change specific text color string-array in string

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `string-array` with somes `item` (for my main menu -> `NavigationDrawer`).

I have somes elements, but i want **have 1 item in specific color**.

I've try this but that's not work

```
<string-array name="navDrawerItems">
    <item>Value</item>
    <item>Value</item>
    <item>
        <![CDATA[
            <p style="color:#c62828">Value</p>
        ]]>
    </item>
    <item>Value</item>
    <item>Value</item>
</string-array>
```

In the `Navigation Drawer` in my app, we see : `<p style="color:#c62828">Value</p>`.

Do you have any idea for color one specific item ?

Thanks

Comment: The Value should be a color code. you can simply google color codes. Then set the color of your text by calling getResources() method. Let me know if that is not clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help :)